# No shared framework schemes

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, carthage

I'm trying to convert an open source project that I do not own to use Carthage so I can include it as a dependency.  I added a new scheme and have made that scheme Shared.  I checked it in to my local git repo of the source.  This is in my Cartfile:

```
git "file:///Users/crystaltwix/Projects/plcrashreporter" "shared-scheme"
```

When I try to run

```
carthage update --platform iOS
```

I do see that Carthage checks out plcrashreporter with the correct git hash, but the error I get is

```
*** Skipped building plcrashreporter due to the error:
Dependency "plcrashreporter" has no shared framework schemes for any of the platforms: iOS
```

Is there something else that needs to be done in order to have a framework be available through Carthage?

Comment: Open the project inside `Carthage/build/iOS/plcrashreporter` check the framework target, is the `shared` flag enabled?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini Yes it is checked as shared.

Comment: is this the framework? https://github.com/plausiblelabs/plcrashreporter

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini Yes that is the one.

Comment: I did integrate the project with Carthage, but since the project is quite obsolete, I had to fork a pull request. I'll post below my results.

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini Was there something obvious I just missed (besides the project being old)?

Comment: In theory you was right (cartfile, and shared scheme enabled). Anyway you may check my answer below, before to be able to release it as a framework, there are many things to fix inside such project.

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini do u have general advice in going about updating the project like u did? I looked at ur commits and it and most of the options that u changed I would never have known about. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did integrate the `plcrashreporter` framework with Carthage, but since the project is quite obsolete, I had to fork a pull request which is this one:

https://github.com/plausiblelabs/plcrashreporter/pull/9

as you can see, there are many commits there (`#34`), some related specifically to Carthage, some others for cleanup and fixing the targets.

You can find the repo here:

https://github.com/feelform/plcrashreporter

My test (you may find it [here](https://github.com/mugx/CrashReporterTest)) has the following:

Cartfile: `github "feelform/plcrashreporter"`

In build settings, Run Script:

/bin/sh: `/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks`

Input files: `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/CrashReporter.framework`

Output files:`$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)/CrashReporter.framework`

Comment: Have you been able to get this project to build with a podspec also?  I have not.